# Hyperledger Burrow: "could not create Burrow kernel: info.Moniker must be valid non-empty ASCII text without tabs, but got"

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-burrow

Hello fellow bugseekers,

I am trying to run a hyperledger burrow blockchain on a v-server.

Installation and setup went just fine, but every time I try to start the chain (`burrow start --validator-address=50B1A9AB9B35B9E9565F4B881018380566702562`) I get this Error:

```
could not create Burrow kernel: info.Moniker must be valid non-empty ASCII text without tabs, but got
```

It seems as tho the log is not complete, but there is nothing after "got", so I assume the info.Moiker is empty. Googeling didn't help. I would appreciate any input.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  had the same problem. **info.Moniker** is just a string value that represents a human readable name. This is related to the Tendermint consensus, which is used by the Hyperledger Burrow.
You can edit *burrow.toml* file and replace
Moniker = ""
with the following -
Moniker = "SomeName"

You can find a sample tendermint toml file [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883452/hyperledger-burrow-could-not-create-burrow-kernel)

BTW, this worked for me.

Comment: Thank You so much, this worked. I see that you created an account just to help me, i appreciate it. <3

Comment: Thank you :) @SimonSchuler
I hope I can be in touch with you, cause I'm also working with Hyperledger Burrow and I might need you help too.

Comment: sure, just check out my Github: https://github.com/SchulerSimon there should be an email if you wanna contact me :)